# Aspect programming using Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, aop, mixins

I am looking for some detailed example with code where I the Aspect Oriented programming is implemented using Backbone.Advice mixin.

I have looked at following links but those are not that intutive and I am finding it difficult to integrate that into my Backbone MV* application.

```
https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/Backbone.Advice
```

Also can someone tell me whether using advice can I access the original parameters passed to the method around which the advice gets applied.

Edit: answering your questions here in original thread

Q: What are you really looking for? Trait based composition and conflict resolution by method modifiers like before, after, around or real Aspect-oriented programming?

A: I have few views which which are inherited from a common view, Now all this view contents their own implementation for render, I would like apply a advice i.e. after every render do some custom stuff etc.

Comment: Regarding the `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for some detailed example with code ...

Unfortunately I'm not able to point you somewhere on that. But I might be able to provide help for the rest.

> ...  where ... the Aspect Oriented programming is implemented using Backbone.Advice mixin.

Having a look into the source code, "Backbone.Advice" does not provide any functionality for Aspect-oriented programming.

But - as the first sentence at [`Backbone.Advice`](https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/Backbone.Advice) states - it does provide "Functional mixins for Backbone based on Advice by Angus Croll". Thus it provides its own mechanics of how to solve composition conflicts if one is going to use `Mixin`s like `Trait`s.

Q: What are you really looking for? Trait based composition and conflict resolution by method modifiers like `before`, `after`, `around` or real Aspect-oriented programming?

Q: What are you trying to achieve?

> Also can someone tell me whether using advice can I access the original parameters passed to the method around which the advice gets applied.

Looking into the source code of `Backbone.Advice` again ...

https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/Backbone.Advice/blob/master/advice.js#L36
https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/Backbone.Advice/blob/master/advice.js#L48
https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/Backbone.Advice/blob/master/advice.js#L64

... the answer is "Definitely yes".

Answer (score 1):

> I have few views which which are inherited from a common view, Now all
>   this view contents their own implementation for render, I would like
>   apply a advice i.e. after every render do some custom stuff etc.

Backbone makes this stuff pretty easy to do just by wrapping prototype functions.  For example:

```
var originalRender = Backbone.View.prototype.render;
Backbone.View.prototype.render = function() {
  // do some stuff before the view renders
  originalRender.apply(this, arguments);
  // do some stuff after the view renders
}
```

Note that in this example I've done this to Backbone.View but you could just as easily do it to a 'subclass' if you only want this behavior to happen for certain views.

Comment: I just gave an example of render method but in my use case its something else which i want to call, is this only possible for render or for any method? Also this is global meaning to all views inside my application but I only want to apply to few hierarchies..

Comment: You can use this technique on just about anything in backbone